# How do I configure the mock server?

Tags: testing, authentication-authorization

According to the documentation, the test module included with the [LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module  should  contain the mock LDAP server.

Where can I find it after enabling this module?
How should I configure it so that I can start testing logging in with a LDAP server?

Answer (score 2):

The "Mock LDAP" server that is being used for the LDAP Test module is, in fact, a mock server object. It allows the tests to run, and doesn't exist outside the scope of the simpletests.

If you're looking to provide a way to "mock" an LDAP instance on your development site, it can't provide that functionality.

If you're trying to write your own simpletests for LDAP integration, check out the [Examples for Developers project](https://dgo.to/examples). The included module, `simpletest_example`, has excellent documentation for writing simple tests.